# Amplitude Modulation in dispersive mediums

Tags: waves, vibrations

I'm reading the book "Physics of Waves" by Georgi. In section 10.2 he says that to send a signal through one-dimensional dispersive mediums where the dispersion relation is not $\omega(k)=vk$ ($v$ the phase velocity and $k$ the wave number). If the signal is defined by a function $f_s(t)$, then the source of the wave should act by a driving force:
$$f(t)=f_s(t)\cos\omega_0 t.$$

Then he writes: you can get a sense of what is going to happen in this case by considering the sum of two traveling waves with different frequencies and wave numbers:

$$\cos((k_0+k_s)x-(\omega_0+\omega_s)t)+\cos((k_0-k_s)x-(\omega_0-\omega_s)t).$$

Here both waves satisfy: $\omega_0=k_0v_0$ and $\omega_s$. I don't understand two things:

1. The relation between $f(t)$ and the sum of the two traveling waves.
2. Even if this relation is valid (I don't see the relation really) why does each wave behave like a travelling wave in a non-dispersive medium?

Answer (score 3):

1. The relationship is true by dint of the trigonometric identity $\cos(u+v)+cos(u-v)=2\,\cos u\,\cos v$. A compelling experiment is to listen to two tones a few hertz apart (the LHS of the identity) and hear the throbbing beats (the AM wave on the RHS). A pitch fork and a guitar / violin string (the latter readily tunable) is a good way to do this;
2. Given the relationship, each wave behaves as an individual travelling wave in a linear medium. But they are *still* dispersed. This is because each term is modulated by the $f(t)$: to be sure, the two carriers are one frequency, but the Fourier transform of $f(t)\,\cos(\omega\,t)$ has a nonzero spectral spread.

So, notwithstanding the appearance of two tones, AM signals suffer dispersion.

Comment: But is $f(t)=\cos(u+v)+\cos(u-v)$? I understand that $f_s(t)$ is any periodic function (that can be written as a combination of harmonic displacements by Fourier's theorem), but I don't get why one can write $f(t)$ as that sum of two travelling waves.